# Kaluza Klein Particles and Mini Black Holes

Tags: black-holes, kaluza-klein

Are the Kaluza Klein Particles and Mini Black Holes associated with the ADD and Randal-Sundrum models different names for the same class of particles or are they distinct.

Answer (score 4):

They are distinct. The mini-black holes are objects that are localized in the bulk and are approximate Schwarzschild thermal ensembles formed by high-energy collisions of incoming particles. The Kaluza Klein excitations are particles zooming around the extra dimensions, and are not thermal, but just as cold as any other single particle states.

The only link between them is inasmuch as you can consider any particle in string theory as a little quantum extremal black hole, but in low-energy physics, they are unrelated.

One should say that the whole project was ruled out from neutrino masses and proton decay, before it was even proposed. It was only proposed in an insincere manner, as a wishful way to get experimental predictions from string theory. In fact, the arbitrariness associated with making the Planck scale large is not only experimentally excluded from qualitative observations of renormalizability, it also ruins any predictivity string theory has, since you can stuff anything you want in large extra dimensions, and the failure to match experiment is only from non-renormalizable interactions, which you can then fine tune to your heart's desire.